# Change Press Down Color of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I tap or hold one of the cells in the UITableView the color of the cell becomes gray by default. I want it to be some other color. I looked everywhere in the storyboard and on stack overflow but could't find it. How do we do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change it like this, which will be red for example:

```
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension based to @evgeny-karkan answer

```
extension UITableViewCell {

   func changePressDownColor(to Color: UIColor){
       let bgColorView = UIView()
       bgColorView.backgroundColor = Color
       self.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
   } 
}
```

Usage:

```
cell.changePressDownColor(to: .red)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the selection after selecting the cell, where it currently says default.

[image]

however, this is very limited number of selection.
if you want custom, you should do it programatically.

i.e./ cell.selectedBackgroundView = customView with color

Comment: When you choose Blue, it doesn't change anything

Comment: my bad, for some reason, the xcode selection change doesn't work. if anyone has a reason why, please tell us,

in meanwhile, setting the backgroundview seems to work. thanks